# Get length of line on tkinter.canvas in inches (Mac OS)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm currently running Mac OS Sonoma 14.2.1 and I'm trying to set up a tkinter canvas which is scaled to "actual" real-life size. I.e., if I draw a line between any two points on the canvas, I'd like to calculate its length in inches.

I've tried getting the DPI in tkinter like so:

```
root = tk.Tk()
dpi = round(root.winfo_fpixels('1i'))
```

On my MacBook, this returns `72`, which seems like a sensible DPI

Then I used the distance formula to calculate the length of the line in pixels
(I don't need crazy precision, so that's why `round` is used here)

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(line)
length = round(math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2))
```

Here's a barebones example of everything together. Note that I'm using `bbox()` here because in actuality the lines will be drawn between two points set with the mouse, so they can be at any angle, not just a static straight line like in this example...

```
import math
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
# get dpi
dpi = round(root.winfo_fpixels('1i'))
# init canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
# create a (supposedly) 1 inch line, for example
line = canvas.create_line(50, 50, dpi + 50, 50, width=2)
# get line endpoints
x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(line)
# calculate line length
length_in_px = round(math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2))
length_in_inches = length_in_px / dpi
# result
print(length_in_inches)  # => 1.0833333333333333 inches?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

So the math (sort of?) checks out. I suspect this floating point weirdness is related to `bbox`, so if anyone has a better suggestion for getting the endpoints of the line, let me know!* (For completeness' sake, removing `round` from both `dpi` and `length_in_px` results in a slightly different weird float: `1.0857189357495975`)

<sup>*SEE FIRST UPDATE</sup>

*But* the real issue is that when I physically measure the line on my laptop's display (literally, with calipers), it's actually 0.555 inches. This, to me, means at least one of two things:

1. There's some UI scaling going on, in which case the question becomes **how do I figure out this scaling factor on Mac OS?** (I have experience doing this on Windows, but I can't figure it out on my Mac)
2. The DPI value returned by `winfo_fpixels()` is incorrect; this seems less likely to me, but not impossible. In this case, **how do I find the actual DPI of my display(s)?**

How can I accurately go about translating pixels to real-world units? Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE 1**

using `canvas.coords(line)` instead of `canvas.bbox(line)` to get the endpoints resolves the floating point weirdness, but not the scaling issue - that's one thing down!

---

**UPDATE 2**

Tech specs for my laptop (2021 M1 MacBook Pro) state that the display DPI is 254...I'm not sure what to do with this info as yet

Comment: could be helpful https://community.activestate.com/t/tk-scaling-on-retina-display-144dpi/6715/3